# ASP.NET service send JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http

I'm trying to make my service send a JSON response along with a status code, but not really sure how to do that. For example, as a response to the POST request, I'd like to send a 201 Created response. So far what I have is this.

**EmployeeApiController.cs**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/employee")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
{

    readonly EmployeePersistence persistence;


    public EmployeeApiController()
    {
        persistence = new EmployeePersistence();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]EmployeeDto employee)
    {
        long id = persistence.SaveEmployee(employee);

        // create http response
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, String.Format("/api/employee/{0}", id));

        return response;
    }
```

Now that returns `text/html` instead of a JSON. I tried changing my return type to `IHttpActionResult` and then `return Json(response)` but that didn't work. How should that be done?

Comment: why are your set route("") you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

Add `[Produces("application/json")]` to your class decoration

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[RoutePrefix("api/employee")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

And change you controller method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]EmployeeDto employee)
{
    long id = persistence.SaveEmployee(employee);
    return Created('employee',new {id = id});
}
```

This should solve the problem